# catch the exception of a subprocess called by another function

Tags: python, exception, subprocess, wrapper

I would like to automate a script execution on a subprocess, so I am using `subprocess` lib to create the thread and `schedule` lib to schedule it.

I would like to verify that the script remotely executed, is working without problems.
The code I was trying does not print any error when the script returns 1 (error) or when the `script_file` is absent. (And if I am not mistaken, adding the exception wrapper kills the subprocess and do its job )

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import multiprocessing
import schedule
import time
import functools

class MyClass:

        def catch_exceptions(job_func):
                @functools.wraps(job_func)
                def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                        try:
                                job_func(*args, **kwargs)
                        except:
                                import traceback
                                print ("Error")
                                print(traceback.format_exc())
                return wrapper


        @catch_exceptions
        def run(self, user, host, command):
                subprocess.call(["ssh", user + "@" + host, command])


        def sched(user, host, script_path):          
               schedule.every(0.01).minutes.do(self.run, user, host, script_path)
```

All suggestions are welcome, using wrappers is not the goal, but any solution to verify the execution of `sched` method is good also.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `subprocess.Popen()`

```
RunCmd = Popen( sCmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

for sLine in RunCmd.stdout:
            print( sLine.decode() )
            stdout.flush()
            aLog.append( sLine.decode() )
for sLine in RunCmd.stderr:
            print( sLine.decode() )
            stderr.flush()
            aErrorLog.append( sLine.decode() )
RunCmd.wait()
if RunCmd.returncode == 0:
            return RunCmd.wait()
        else: 
            return RunCmd.returncode
```

RunCmd.wait() will wait for the process to finish, and will return process code(for succuss or failure)
This also prints the output at realtime.

Comment: if both stdout and stderr are redirected then you should read them both concurrently otherwise the program may hang forever. In addition, OP doesn't redirect the output of the remote subprocess.

Comment: FYI : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29
"streams are independent and can be redirected separately". I have never faced any issue with this code.

Comment: It just mean that the output was small in all your cases. Imagine what happens when `sCmd` prints to stderr the content that (accumulatively) is larger than OS pipe buffer: your parent process is trying to read from stdout while the child tries to write to stderr but its stderr pipe buffer is full -- deadlock. There is a warning about it in the subprocess docs.

Comment: Believe me, output was big enough to choke the stream to deadlock, but I am flushing the streams to handle the deadlock. I can freely use `Popen.wait()` since my buffers are always empty to accept more  input from streams.

Comment: *where* do you flush the streams? If OS pipe buffer is full. It is full. The only thing that you could do is read it but you can't because your code reads the other stream that is why I said: read them *both* **concurrently**. Just try: `for c in 'x'*(1<<20): for f in [sys.stdout, sys.stderr]: print >>f, c` as a child and see how your code deals with it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print
`stdout.flush()` flush the OS pipes after each print statement?

Comment: no, `stdout.flush()` moves data from *internal* stdout process buffer into the corresponding OS pipe buffer. Try the code from my previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

`call` returns the exit code of process. So you can check against that. Or try `subprocess.check_call`. It throws an exception when the process exits with a non-zero value, so you don't have to explicitly check the exit value, and catch the exception where you want to deal with it.

Examples:

```
exit_value = subprocess.call(cmd) 
if exit_value:
    ...
```

or

```
try:
    subprocess.check_call(cmd) 
except CalledProcessError as e:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x=subprocess.Popen(["ssh", user + "@" + host, command],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output,error=x.communicate()
if error:
    print "there's an error!!!!!!!!!!!!!!:",error
```

You can try like this.`subprocess.communicate` returns `output` if successful or `error` if command fails.